# Error inserting image in CKEditor

Tags: php, html, mysql, ckeditor

I am using `CKEditor` in php and what I am trying to do is to store data from `CKEditor` to `MySQL` table. When I try to store data it works fine on localhost but the problem is when I put it online.

I am inserting path in `CKEditor` from image tool and the path is like *www.xxx.com/myfolder/abc.jpg* this shows image in `CKEditor` but when click on submit it gives `\"\"` when I try to print that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, to remove the back slashes add by the CKeditor to fix this issue,

```
stripslashes($_POST['content']);
```